# Grafana: Dashboard with selectable unit systems

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I have a datasource that is all in metric units.  Let's say I have a series of distance that's in meters.  I want to have a graph showing this distance over time.

The problem is I would like to have a variable at the top of the dashboard where I can select km / mi as the distance unit.  Right now I can set this up with the values `km : 1,mi : 1.6` and multiply the metric by this.  The query I'm working on now does

```
rivian_distance_to_empty_meters{instance="$vehicle"} / $distance_ratio / 1000
```

The issue is I don't know how to set the units for the graph.

[image]

Is there a way of dynamically setting the unit based on the label?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot set units from variable. As a workaround, you can join a synthetic label with content of the variable label to your metric, and then use Transformation *Config from query results* to specify Unit based on the label.